# How do I split a Scrollview layout in half to show parent background color and two panes?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I have a simple UI screen with a white background.  Then I have Scrollview  with 10 dp margins all around and black background, so basically a rectangle within a rectangle.  How would I split the Scrollview in half so that I can show a white horizontal line in the middle of the inside black rectangle, thus creating two black panes?  The uploaded pic below shows what I have currently (please ignore the tiny outside colored border that was captured to show the main UI white background.

layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"  >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    >

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/xyztext"
    android:text="xyz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: You can't split the scrollView, you will need to change the layout. Do you need to scroll both black rectangles together or make them to scroll independently?

Comment: I need to scroll both together so user can scroll the full vertical distance from the top of the UI to the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to set the black background to the two rectangles instead of setting it to the ScrollView, which you can't split. 
Also a ScrollView can only host one direct child and then add to it the two layouts that conforms your rectangle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/MainLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/black">
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/MainLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="700dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/black">

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This will give you the following UI:

[image: UI result]

Note that I've put a Space element to separate the two Linear Layouts. You can replace it with a margin if you prefer.

Comment: Ok I will try that.  Is the transparent color for the ScrollView background a way for it to just keep the parent color, in this case white?

Comment: Yes, I've set the color white in the root element. Also if you don't set any background they will be transparent by default

Comment: Thanks, I will test tomorrow as I've run out of time now.  I think it will work fine so answer accepted and upvoted.  Cheers!

Comment: If you have any problem on it just comment it I will look at it. Cheers

Comment: Excellent.  I plan to work again on it about 24 hours from now, so will post a follow-up if I run into any issues.

Comment: Hi, how did you select size for each of the two Linear Layouts, 300dp and 700dp?  Shouldn't I be trying to do something with layout weights rather than putting in arbitrary sizes that may be much bigger or smaller than the UI screen size?

Comment: Hi. I just use those sizes to force the scroll, as The second rectangle wont fit in the screen. It depends on what you have to do. I will use wrap_content to fit the heights to its content, so you will only have the scroll if your elements are bigger than the screen. With weights you are dividing the layout un equal parts and asigning them to the elements, so they will have the same size independently of its content